# How to choose printer in Metro-style app

Tags: c#, printing, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm trying to convert an existing desktop app into **metro style app** (Win8 & VS12).
but i'm having a hard time dealing with the printing.

my software has two users - "Admin" and "User". 
I want the "Admin" to be able to choose printer and printer settings,
and the "User" need to press on "Print" button, and that's it.

the troubles are:

1. I can't find how to get all connected printers. (`DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync()` requires `DeviceClass` which has these options only -  `All, AudioCapture, AudioRender, PortableStorageDevice, VideoCapture`). 
   [in my original app (WPF), i'm using `PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters`]
2. I can't find a way to print to a selected printer (even if I already know the name).
   since (as far as i understand), the only way to print is to open (using code or registration) the "charms" bar, and let the user to choose the printer.
   What if i don't want the user to use a specified printer ?
3. Is there a way to reference a "normal" C# dll that will do the "dirty stuff" for the metro-style app ? When i'm trying, i'm getting "Unable to add reference to project 'Try1'". is there's a way to bypass it ?

thank you very much in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printing in a Windows Store app is now [handled by a task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.printing.printtask.aspx). You don't have to do all the work of finding the printers and making the user select one, that's now handled by Windows.

Comment: But that's not the case. I WANT to choose a specific printer. and NOT letting the user to do it.

Comment: Right. And I'm telling you that's not how it works in Windows Store applications. Microsoft wants to provide Windows 8 users with a unified experience, where everything works exactly how it's expected to (e.g. they click on the print charm and then they get to select a printer) and there's not a way to circumvent that.

Comment: 1. so you are saying that it's impossible to do thing like [this](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2008/11/programmatically-selecting-complex-printer-options-in-c-shar/) ? 2. what about my third question ?

Comment: 1. Yes. The APIs used in that example aren't available to Windows Store apps. 2. Basically the same thing; Windows Store apps can't reference regular .NET assemblies.

Comment: thank you for clarifying this. I'll accept your answer (with sorrow).